What the differences between these 3 for loops?
def generate_coor(dimension_x,dimension_y):
    x,y=int(dimension_x/2),int(dimension_y/2)
    for i in range(0, x + 1):
        print(x)
        x=x+1

generate_coor(100,27)

The above code does terminate.
def generate_coor(dimension_x,dimension_y):
    x,y=int(dimension_x/2),int(dimension_y/2)
    for i in range(0, x + 1):
        for j in range(0, y + 1):
            print(y)
            y=y+1

generate_coor(100,27)

The above code does not terminate
def generate_coor(dimension_x,dimension_y):
    x,y=int(dimension_x/2),int(dimension_y/2)
    for i in range(0, y):
        for j in range(0, y + 1):
            print(y)
            y=y+1

The above code does terminate
What the differences between these 3 examples? According to the code, each iteration for x or y should be increase by 1 hence the loop should not terminate but some terminate, some does not?

For the middle example, if you move print(y) to the end of the function, and then do generate_coor(1, 27), generate_coor(2, 27), ... and so on, it will output a sequence like "27 55 55 111 111 223 ...". Thus, the function is effectively calculating (dy * 2 ** (dx // 2)) + (2 ** (dx // 2) - 1). For generate_coor(100, 27) this will eventually output 31525197391593471.

All loops will terminate, but the time to do so depends on the value you enter as parameter inputs.
What happens in your 2nd example :
def generate_coor(dimension_x,dimension_y):
    x,y=int(dimension_x/2),int(dimension_y/2)
    for i in range(0, x + 1):
        for j in range(0, y + 1):
            print(y)
            y=y+1

is that your nested loop for j in range(0, y + 1)  is repeating itself for each iteration of the first loop for i in range(0, x + 1).
This is particularly time consuming in your case with generate_coor(100,27) being given the CPU time required to execute the function will be exponential with respect to your two integer inputs.
If you take lower values, e.g. generate_coor(10,10), you'll see the function exiting.
